# I need a simple HTML5 Fill Preloader (heart shape progress bar)

Tags: html, flash, preloader

I am using Flash CC 2015. I want to make a preloader in HTML5 Canvas just like the one I used in AS3. I'm converting my "flash website" piece by piece, so I'm beginning with the preloader.

Currently I use the following in flash AS3:

```
stop();

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);

function loading(e:Event):void {

    var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

    bar_mc.scaleX = loaded/total;

    if (total == loaded) {
        play();
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
    }
}
```

It is a heart outline with pink fill. I used a mask named bar_mc to do the expanding, revealing the heart shaped fill behind it.

Would like one just like it for HTML5 Canvas. Complete instructions would be appreciated if possible.

You can see the current one in action (unless your internet is too fast, try mobile) at hugclub.net  Thank you folks!

PS - Current progress bar tutorials for HTML5 are relevant only for embedded movies, not the actual opening of a website, so I ask now :) Hope it helps others too.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this yourself yet? Please post what you've tried.

Comment: I tried 2 things. Copy the frames out of the timeline from the AS3 fla file, to the timeline of the Canvas fla file. Also tried the Command menu and exported as Canvas.

They both had the exact same results. "Script has been commented" and all it did was add  */ to all my actionscript.. I was under the impression Flash CC made some attempt to convert AS3 to HTML5, guess it doesn't..? :(

Otherwise all I can do at this point is read up on basic functions and post questions :)